# How to open a file type file

Tags: excel, ssis

I am using an SSIS for each loop  to read multiple excel files and move them to an archive folder, but I forgot to create an archive folder and SSIS automatically move the excel files to .file format which is called archive, because I put the destination folder in a variable by directing the directory to an archive folder, but there was no archive folder, so SSIS put all the excel files to an archive file type  and I couldn't open the file type archive file. what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Does re-naming to excel file type to .xlsx / .xls helped ? Can you show us the image with whatever you are  referring ?

Comment: I'd say check that you're specifying the file extension (`.xls`, `.xlsx`) when copying/moving to a folder.